# step function matching AIC of full model

Tags: r, regression, model-comparison

Shouldn't the

```
AIC(full) = 275.93
```

match the output of of the AIC when the step() function runs with the full model which is -9.86 below

```
Start:  AIC=-9.86
y ~ x + x2

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS      AIC
- x2    1   0.03672 85.372 -11.8147
- x     1   1.03869 86.374 -10.6479
<none>              85.336  -9.8578

Step:  AIC=-11.81
y ~ x

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
- x     1     1.004 86.376 -12.646
<none>              85.372 -11.815

Step:  AIC=-12.65
y ~ 1


Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 1, data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
   -0.03719
```

here is the full code:

```
set.seed(101)
y = rnorm(100)
x = rnorm(100)
x2 = rnorm(100)
data = data.frame(y = y, x = x, x2 = x2)
null = lm(y~1, data = data)
full = lm(y~x+x2, data = data)
#step(null, scope= list(lower = null, upper = full) , direction="backward", trace = TRUE)
step(full, direction="backward", trace = TRUE)
AIC(full)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need `extractAIC` instead of `AIC`

```
extractAIC(lm(y~x+x2, data = data), scale=0)
#OR
#extractAIC(full, scale=0)
```

If you refer the documentation `?AIC` & `?extractAIC` it clearly says that

> The log-likelihood and hence the AIC/BIC is only defined up to an
>   additive constant. Different constants have conventionally been used
>   for different purposes and so extractAIC and AIC may give different
>   values (and do for models of class **"lm"**: see the help for extractAIC).

Hope this helps!